# Roslyn ISyntaxFactoryService

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

In Roslyn, you can generate syntax tree by using `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SyntaxFactory`, for example:

```
SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NumericLiteralExpression, SyntaxFactory.Literal(1))
```

In Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces, there is an internal interface [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeGeneration.ISyntaxFactoryService`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/CodeGeneration/ISyntaxFactoryService.cs), implemented by [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CodeGeneration.CSharpSyntaxFactory`](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/CodeGeneration/CSharpSyntaxFactory.cs), which wraps calls to `SyntaxFactory` with some additional logic, so it seems to be a more high-level (and language independent) way of generating code.

What is the purpose of this factory service? Why is this service internal? Is there any public API for source code generation more high-level than `SyntaxFactory`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many questions all in one question.

1. What is the purpose of this factory service? To create syntax in a language independent manner.
2. Why is this service internal? Because it hasn't been specified, reviewed, documented, tested for public consumption, verified that it will be supported indefinitely, etc.
3. Is there any public API for source code generation more high-level than `SyntaxFactory`.  No, not at the moment.